# save Excel with date in name

Tags: vba, date, button, save

I am trying to build a macro that will save my Excel file with the specified name (customer and date).
Not working so far and as I am not very fluent in VBA maybe someone here would be willing to help:

```
Sub Save()

    Sheets("Tool").Unprotect Password:="xxxx"


    Dim fclient As String
    Dim path As String


    fclient = Range("G11").Value
    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path


    fname = "Discount for " & fclient

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY"), FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False

    Sheets("Tool").Protect Password:="xxxx"


End Sub
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem here?  What does unprotecting a worksheet have to do with saving the file?  What is `path`?  Are you getting an error?  If  `path` ended in a file separator `\` then that will throw an error.

Comment: The protecting sheet is necessary because it is a tool. The path is indicated because I want the new file to be saved in the same location as the source file. It is working if I don't add the part " & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")" but u need that date in the file name

Comment: Are you using MAC OS?

Comment: no, windows, excel 2016

Comment: There is no reason for it to fail.  I would set a breakpoint at ` Application.ActiveWorkbook.` and then test the full path in the `Immediate Window` (e.g. `?path & "\" & fname & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")`)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the `Format(Now(DD-MM-YYYY))` directly into your path, you can set the date into a cell in the sheet and then use the cells value as part of the file name the same as you have done for the clients name.

The `Date` function [uses your current system date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-function) in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format rather than `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` which `Now` uses.

I've adapted this to your code along with a 'find and replace' code to find the "/" in the date and replace it with "_". (**NOTE** this was simply recorded and could be written better I'm sure.) You could change the underscore to any other valid character for a file name if you wish.

In my test I removed `Path` as [if you omit a path in the file name it will use the current files path.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel)

```
Sub Save()

Dim fclient As String
Dim tdate As String

Range("G12") = Date

tdate = Range("G12")
fclient = Range("G11")

    Cells(12, 7).Replace What:="/", Replacement:="_", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

tdate = Range("G12")
fname = "Discount for " & fclient

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\" & fname & "_" & tdate _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I've assumed cell G12 is able to contain the date.

Why your original code doesn't work i'm not sure but this is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Activeworkbook`